# Confusion with classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember in the JVM spec, and more generally rules for accessing a protected member

Tags: java, prolog, jvm, specifications, jls

The Java [jvms](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se12/jvms12.pdf) states:

> The predicate classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember(Class, MemberName,MemberDescriptor, MemberClassName, Chain, List) is true if List is the set of classes in Chain with name MemberClassName that are in a different run-time package  than  Class  which  have  a  protected  member named MemberName with descriptor MemberDescriptor.

```
classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember(_, _, _, _, [], []).

classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember(Class, MemberName,
    MemberDescriptor, MemberClassName,
    [class(MemberClassName, L) | Tail],
    [class(MemberClassName, L) | T]) :-
    differentRuntimePackage(Class, class(MemberClassName, L)),
    loadedClass(MemberClassName, L, Super),
    isProtected(Super, MemberName, MemberDescriptor),
    classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember(
    Class, MemberName, MemberDescriptor, MemberClassName, Tail, T).

classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember(Class, MemberName,
    MemberDescriptor, MemberClassName,
    [class(MemberClassName, L) | Tail],T) :-
    differentRuntimePackage(Class, class(MemberClassName, L)),
    loadedClass(MemberClassName, L, Super),
    isNotProtected(Super, MemberName, MemberDescriptor),
    classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember(
    Class, MemberName, MemberDescriptor, MemberClassName, Tail, T).

classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember(Class, MemberName,
                                    MemberDescriptor, MemberClassName,
                                    [class(MemberClassName, L) | Tail],
                                    T) :-
    sameRuntimePackage(Class, class(MemberClassName, L)),
    classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember(
    Class, MemberName, MemberDescriptor, MemberClassName, Tail, T).
```

However looking at the definition of `classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember`(above), we see that the defs of `classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember` always pop `class(MemberClassName, L)` from Chain. Given a simple super-class chain such as below, `classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember` will always fail, since it cannot pop a class with the same name for every element of the chain. More specifically it is forced to always pop a class with the name `MemberClassName`.

```
    class('java/util/HashMap',bootstrapLoader)
    class('java/util/AbstractMap',bootstrapLoader),
    class('java/lang/Object',bootstrapLoader)
```

Am I misinterpreting this Prolog code, or does `classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember` fail for all non-trivial values of `Chain`? Does this somehow rely on backtracking to get a simpler `Chain`, which can then succeed? Is there some sort of flexible concept of name, where sometimes `MemberClassName` refers to an unqualified name, and sometimes refers to the name + package? Should there be a `MemberClassName1` and a `MemberCLassName2`, such that the same class is not popped from Chain every time?

Comment: Perhaps I should have tagged this prolog to get some prolog programmers to view this.

Comment: `Given a simple super-class chain such as below, classesInOtherPkgWithProtectedMember will always fail, since it cannot pop a class with the same name for every element of the chain.`  Why do you say this?

Comment: Capitalized Prolog in my question body.

Comment: @GuyCoder the 5th parameter is always popping a class(MemberClassName, _), and the same MemberClassName is always passed recursively as the 4th parameter. This means that the 5th parameter(the chain) would need to be elements with only the same name.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the a trace of this during a real run of the code. I am wondering if what you think is in a parameter is different than what is actually in the parameter. Also this is Prolog, which means that if a predicate is called, it does not necessarily complete. Each line in the predicate must complete successfully before the next line is called.

Comment: Just to avoid assumptions, do you know Prolog, unification and backtracking?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the specs, it is nice to have, but for me I really need to see the values of the parameters at this point from a real run of the code. Are there any test cases for the predicate?

Comment: @GuyCoder I doubt that there is a “real run of the code” at all. These Prolog snippets have been used to specify the constraints of the verifier, but I’m sure that every actual verifier has been implemented in a language like C/C++ or Java. It would be interesting to know, how close these implementations actually follow the logic mandated by these Prolog fragments. I already made a comment about the apparent mismatch between the choice of specification language and the expected target audience of the specification, but it has been removed.

Comment: @Holger You are free to answer this question and I will be happy to leave it alone so that I can continue my own work. :)

Comment: @GuyCoder it seems, you are misunderstanding my comment. I’m saying, the information in the linked spec is all we got. There are no additional information, except perhaps in the depths of Oracle’s unpublished stuff. The authors of the spec expect us readers to interpret the code in our brain, to conclude what to do, e.g. when implementing an actual verifier in whatever language. I can’t do that. If an experienced Prolog programmer like you says that this is impossible without further information, we would have to tell Oracle, that the specification is incomplete.

Comment: @Holger I seriously doubt the code is wrong, but won't say it is wrong without much more evidence. Also I read some more of the spec and found this to be of interest `the gradual removal of the jsr and jsr_w instructions from the
Java SE Platform`. If it were not for that statement, I would probably walk away from this question.

Comment: One question I currently have in seeking to answer this question is are they using [Hindley–Milner type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system)? I don't expect anyone to answer this, but it is value to know in answering in this question.

Comment: Of interest: [Java Language and Virtual Machine Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/index.html) Has links to HTML version of spec that has links. Note that latest version *Java SE 13 Edition* is not the same as the version of this question: *Java SE 12 Edition* as determined from the linked specification in the question.

Comment: @Holger I am setting this aside until the OP answers the question I asked in the comments. I see that he is a university student based on his bio, so have to take that into consideration. i.e. What level of programming does he have. Could he be a grad student doing research?

Comment: Also why is this question not being asked at the Java specifications area. I don't know where it is, but it surely must exist.

Comment: @GuyCoder  
Addressing the comments in the order posted:


> Would it be possible to get the a trace of this during a real run of the code. 
Yes, it would be. I'll try and get this done tonight. Be warned that it could be quite long. But as mentioned above this code is a specification and was never really meant to be run.


> Just to avoid assumptions, do you know Prolog, unification and backtracking?


I have written a few non-trivial Prolog programs.  I am familiar with the aforementioned concepts.

Comment: @GuyCoder
> Also I read some more of the spec and found this to be of interest the gradual removal of the jsr and jsr_w instructions from the Java SE Platform.

I highly doubt this is relevant.

Comment: `Be warned that it could be quite long.` That's fine, I just want to see examples of the input to avoid having to make guesses.

Comment: `But as mentioned above this code is a specification and was never really meant to be run.` The code looks more like real code to me and I would trust running that than running in a system that tried to emulate what it does.

Comment: Here's a trace of verification for the Object class. I'm working on making a trace which reproduces the behavior this question is about.
https://gist.github.com/pirocks/6d0232a180501f99db0c4161ff118be0